# wireless printer on secondary wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, wireless-router

I'm having trouble with the following configuration:

**cable modem----wireless router 1----wireless router 2----wireless printer**

Wireless router 1 has IP 192.168.0.1 with DHCP enabled (192.168.0.1-199).

Wireless router 2 has IP 192.168.0.200 with DHCP disabled, and is connected to wireless router 1 LAN to LAN.

Devices connected to wireless router 1 can't see the wireless printer on router 2.

Any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using printer hostname or IP address to connect to it?

Comment: The printer has IP 192.168.0.104

Comment: The printer can be detected and used by various devices from router 1, but when connected through router 2, those devices see the printer as offline.

Comment: If those routers are connected LAN to LAN (and not the port marked as "internet"), there shouldn't be any NAT related problems. Have you checked is your printer accessed via Host Name (such as HP-SOMETHING-SOMETHING) or IP address? You can do this by checking "ports" under printer properties and editing TCP/IP port of your printer. Can you ping your printers' IP address from router 1?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  (In the previous comment, I accidentally reversed the routers.) Yes, the routers are connected LAN-LAN. Yes, I can ping from router 1.   I'm connecting various Apple devices through the wireless routers - not sure if this answers the question about Host Name vs IP.

Comment: We need to narrow your problem down, there are too many potential problems such as firewall, NAT, duplicate IP, DHCP not relaying... Try connecting to Router 1 and adding the printer again using a computer, but use its IP address not hostname when setting up the connection. On OSX you have to enter hostame or IP address in Add Printer / IP dialogue. If you use Windows add printer wizard will guide you to this setting in one of the steps.